# SQL Server query to retrieve data from two tables with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `Table1` and `Table2`.

`Table1` has the following columns

- date
- u_id
- t_id
- col_t1_a
- col_t1_b
- col_t1_c

and `Table2` has the following columns

- date
- ux_id
- tx_id
- col_t2_a
- col_t2_b
- col_t2_c

Table1.u_id is a sub-string of Table2.ux_id and Table1.t_id = Table2.tx_uid.

I am trying to get all the columns (col_t2_c) from Table2 when all the below conditions are true

- Table1.t_id = Table2.tc_uid and
- substring(Table2.ux_id,7,6) = Table1.u_id and
- Table1.date = Table2.date = 'yymmdd' and
- Table1.col_t1_a = 'A' and
- Table1.col_t1_b = 'B' and
- Table1.col_t1_c = 'C'

I need some help in writing a SQL Server 2008 query to achieve the above.

Any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 T2
INNER JOIN
    Table1 T1 ON T1.t_id = T2.tx_uid
    AND T1.u_id = substring(t2.ux_id, 7, 6)
    AND T1.[Date] = T2.[Date]
WHERE
    T1.[date] = 'date'
    AND T1.col_t1_a = 'A'
    AND T1.col_t1_b = 'B'
    AND t1.col_t1_c = 'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

All your conditions are already written. Just put them into query:

```
SELECT t2.col_t2_c
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t1.t_id = t2.tc_uid and 
        substring(t2.ux_id,7,6) = t1.u_id and
        t1.date = t2.date
WHERE   
        t2.date = 'yymmdd' and 
        t1.col_t1_a = 'A' and
        t1.col_t1_b = 'B' and
        t1.col_t1_c = 'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.t_id = t2.tx_uid 
AND t1.u_id = substring(t2.ux_id,7,6)
AND t1.date = t2.date
AND t2.date = 'yymmdd'
AND t1.col_t1_a = 'A'
AND t1.col_t1_b = 'B'
AND t1.col_t1_c = 'C'
```